# What is the best approach when working with a REST API and big datasets

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I have a data provider(REST Api) that stores info about 400-500k items that gets updated daily. The API methods I can call returns info for 1000 items only (but I have a pagination mechanism so i can loop through all data) .

I'm working with PHP/MySQL and my task is to check a website database(containing 10k to 100k items) against the data provided by this API. All I need to do is to check that the item ID from the website database is present in the provider database. If not, I will delete the record from the website database.

What will be the best method to do this daily ?

Should I first do a loop, get all the data from the data provider and store that into a file ? (considering it is 400-500k ids I don't think an array will do ) Then check each ID from the local database against that file ?

Comment: Why not do the check within the pagination loop. I.e call rest API, process 1000  rows into an array, use array to check in website data then loop to next 1000.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to the ["Rules Of Optimization Club"](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub) - specifically rules 1 and 2:

1. You do not optimize.
2. You do not optimize, without measuring first.

So build a solution that works with what you think of first. Then measure how it performs. If it performs badly, see what parts of it is slow (server responses / saving data / looping through data) and only then start to think about optimization.

This is specifically in response to "considering it is 400-500k ids I don't think an array will do" -- did you try and did it fail?

Comment: Yes - it failed but because of php max execution time . I will try it with that set to 0.

Comment: In that case I would start to remove bits from the end of your algorithm and that way see what is actually taking so long. If the simple getting of data is taking a long time - yeah, you need to split the fetching into batches/chunks.

Comment: Hmm, in that case your question seems to be more "I tried to fetch and process a very large amount of data, but I ran into the PHP max_execution time. How can I do this more performantly (show code here with comments about how long arrays are etc)" :)

Comment: The api response is just an an array with the id's - nothing to optimize . The execution time was taking a long time because we have to wait for apo response (400k listing - we get max 1k listing per request)